# How to run two pwa-msedge debuggers in vscode at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge, vscode-debugger, javascript-debugger, nx.dev

I have two frontend applications in my applications that need to be run in debugger mode, at the same time.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-msedge",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Org Admin - Edge",
      "url": "http://localhost:3001",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-beta"
    },
    {
      "name": "Super Admin - Edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-msedge",
      "url": "http://localhost:3002",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-beta"
    },
    {
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "name": "Start Full Application",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "node-terminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the configuration I have so far, But I am only able to run either the Super Admin - Edge or the Org Admin - Edge at the same time. What I want is to run all of them at the same time when I launch each of them individually.

Basically, the need is to run two "pwa-msedge" instances from VSCode Debugger simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid what you want is impossible. One config can launch one Edge instance and you can only use one config at a time. The only thing you can do is to launch **Org Admin - Edge** and **Super Admin - Edge** one by one. Then both are running and you can debug them.